# BizTalk 2013R2 32bit host

Tags: biztalk, 32bit-64bit, biztalk-2013r2

I have a receive location working on a 64bit host with a schema located in an assembly built in visual studio 2013 (let's call it NameOfMyAssembly). This works fine so far.

Now I need to make it run under a 32bit host (to use an SQL adapter).

When I create the same receive location but on a 32 bit host, I get the following error :

The document specification NameOfMySchema from assembly NameOfMyAssembly failed to load. Verify the schema for this document specification is deployed and is in the Global Assembly Cache.

Do I need to make another schema for my SQL adapter? Or is there a way to deploy my assembly to make it visible to 32 bits hosts?

Comment: Why are you using the SQL adapter rather than the WCF-SQL adapter?

Comment: It also should not matter whether the host is 32bit or 64bit, unless you specifically set the Build, Target Platform of the project containing the schema to x64 rather than any CPU

Comment: Can you clarify exactly which SQL Adapter you're referring to?  The current supported WCF SQL Adapter/sqlBinding or the legacy SQL Adapter.  You should only be using the WCF based Adapter.  Also, all BizTalk Projects should have the Platform target set to Any CPU.

Comment: I'm using the legacy SQL adapter to upgrade from a biztalk 2006 application and have the least possible changes. Is it easy to convert from a SQL to a WCF-SQL adapter?

Comment: Yes. It's easy to convert a sql to a WCF-SQL adapter.It has all the functionality which SQL has plus some extra features.